# How to carry Log-in details from one form to another in a Java desktop application

Tags: java, authentication, singleton

When creating a web app, you can start a session when a user logs in and use session variables to access data specific to that user. I want to know if there is a way to do the same but in a Java desktop application (excluding servlets). So imagine a user logs in on one form, how do i carry there logging details over to another form without having them re-enter those details?

Comment: In the very same place where you are currently storing User Login data to access your Desktop Application.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I can think of two methods:

The first, which I think is more suitable, is to create a singleton class dedicated to holding the program state, like login details. You can update it in the login form and then use it in other forms to access the data. Moreover, it could hold only the user login details and then it could also hold the logic of authentication, forming a unified class for a single purpose.

Another method I can think of is to pass the details to the new form as parameters. The downside is that you'd have to pass the details to any new form using the login details from now on, and that's why I recommend the first option.